# Pulling associated data fields in controller API's with Sequelize / Node

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, rest

I have built a REST api to pull user log data in my Node backend. What is the best course of action to get the fields data of the associated tables? Would I have to manually add to my API the code to pull the data from other tables or is there a easier way of doing this with sequelize? Does this mean the way I have coded my foreign keys are incorrect?

The ID fields below are the ones I need to text data relating to the Int values as they won't mean anything to a user viewing a table on the front-end.

Note: I have the fields data in my Redux store on the front-end so I could also do something there If that is the most common process. I thought that the "include: {all: true}" part would pull the foreign key data but it hasn't worked.

```
    "data": [
        {
            "diveID": 46,
            "diveTypeID": 1,
            "diveSchoolNameID": 4,
            "diveCurrentID": 1,
            "diveVisibilityID": 1,
            "diveDate": "2020-01-09T00:00:00.000Z",
            "diveMaxDepth": 15,
            "diverUserNumber": 6,
            "diveVerifiedBySchool": false,
            "diveNotes": "Cold, poor view, miserable, seen catfish, eels",
            "diveSpotID": null,
            "divePhotos": null
        },
        {
            "diveID": 47,
            "diveTypeID": 1,
            "diveSchoolNameID": 4,
            "diveCurrentID": 1,
            "diveVisibilityID": 1,
            "diveDate": "2020-01-09T00:00:00.000Z",
            "diveMaxDepth": 15,
            "diverUserNumber": 6,
            "diveVerifiedBySchool": false,
            "diveNotes": "Cold, poor view, miserable, seen catfish, eels",
            "diveSpotID": null,
            "divePhotos": null
        },
```

diveLog

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {

  const diveLog = sequelize.define("diveLogs", {

    diveID: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
      allowNull: false
    },
    diveTypeID: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER
    },
    diveSchoolNameID: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER
    },
    diveCurrentID: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER
    },
    diveVisibilityID: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER
    },
    diveDate: {
      type: Sequelize.DATE
    },
    diveMaxDepth: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER
    },
    diverUserNumber: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER
    },
    diveVerifiedBySchool: {
      type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN
    },
    diveNotes: {
      type: Sequelize.TEXT
    },
    diveSpotID: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER
    },
    divePhotos: {
      data: Sequelize.Buffer,
      type: Sequelize.TEXT
    }},
      {
        timestamps: false
      }, {});
    diveLog.associate = function(models){
      diveLog.belongsTo(models.diveRegion, {foreignKey: 'diveRegionID', as: 'diveRegion'})
      diveLog.belongsTo(models.certification, {foreignKey: 'certificationID', as: 'certification'})
      diveLog.belongsTo(models.current, {foreignKey: 'currentID', as: 'current'})
      diveLog.belongsTo(models.visibility, {foreignKey: 'visibilityID', as: 'visibility'})
      diveLog.belongsTo(models.divePoint, {foreignKey: 'diveSpotID', as: 'diveSpot'})
    };

  return diveLog;
};
```

controller method

```
exports.userDiveLog = (req, res) => {

    try {
        const id = req.params.id;

        diveLog.findAll({
            include: {all: true},
            where: {diverUserNumber: id}
        })
            .then(diveLog => {

                const userDiveLogList = [];
                for (i = 0; i < diveLog.length; i++) {
                    userDiveLogList.push(diveLog[i].dataValues);
                }

                if (!userDiveLogList) {
                    return res.status(404).send({message: "No dive logs belonging to this user"});
                }

                res.status(200).send({
                    data: userDiveLogList
                })
            })
    } catch(err) {
            res.status(500).send({
                message: "Error retrieving dive log belonging to user id= " + id
            });
        }
};
```